# How do I make the numbers decrease?

Tags: loops, nested

I`m am doing a nested loop problem and I was wondering how I could make the numbers after they reach a certain number start to decrease. The things I have tried start an infinite loop in the console. Here is an Example of the output wanted.

```
     1
    222
   33333
  4444444
 555555555
  4444444
   33333
    222
     1
```

here is my code :

```
public class DisplayPattern {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int odd = 1;
        int numbOfSpaces = 4;

        for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
            for (int j = numbOfSpaces; j >= 1; j--) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for (int j = 1; j <= odd; j++) {
                System.out.print(i);
            }
            System.out.println();

            if(i < 5) {
                odd = odd + 2;
                numbOfSpaces = numbOfSpaces - 1;
            }
            else {
                odd = odd -2;
                numbOfSpaces = numbOfSpaces + 1;
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the output I am getting:

```
    1
   222
  33333
 4444444
555555555
 6666666
  77777
   888
    9
```

Comment: if(i < 5) {
  System.out.print(i - 10);
}
else{
  System.out.print(i);
}

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this with you code (meaning least amount of mods) is to add a variable NumberToPrint = 1; next to the other declared variables and instead of printing i you print NumberToPrint.
Next you have to increment and decrement the number

```
    if(i < 5) {
        NumberToPrint++;
        //the other stuff still goes here
        ...
    }
    else {
        NumberToPrint--;
        //the other stuff still goes here
        ...
```

Having said that, this is not the right approach. Try to think of a way to make this generic and parametrize everything including the maximum number to go to. See how you can fix you code to work with numbers that have 2 digits or 3... so one.